# extending classes with an array list not working correctly

Tags: java

I have a class that extends my base class.

```
class A extends Base {}
class Base{}
```

//In another class I am trying to override an array list

```
class C {  ArrayList<Base> it = new ArrayList<Base>()}

class D extends C {ArrayList<A> it = new ArrayList<A>()}
```

But I am getting an error?

Sholdn't i be able to in class D insantiate it as A is it extends the base?
Any other ways to do this??
thanks a ton!!

Comment: What error ?????

Comment: It should work. Only thing the variable name `it` hiding the parent class variable.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing two semicolons:

```
class C {  ArrayList<Base> it = new ArrayList<Base>(); }
                                                     ^
                                                    !!!

class D extends C {ArrayList<A> it = new ArrayList<A>(); }
                                                       ^
                                                      !!!
```

And, you need to `import java.util.ArrayList;`

With that, your code compiles fine.